# Null Error thrown after null check?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, nullpointerexception

Can someone please explain why scoreTextSwitcher is getting a null error even though I'm checking with if statement?  The error is thrown only after starting activity - changing screen orientation - changing screen orientation again - then error occurs...

```
if(scoreTextSwitcher != null) {
       scoreTextSwitcher.setText(String.valueOf(a));
}
```

I tried looking for the answer on the links below but couldn't figure out how it relates to my code. If so, can someone please clarify? Many Thanks.

- [NullReferenceException thrown after null check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337791/nullreferenceexception-thrown-after-null-check)
- [Null Pointer Exception after checking with 'if' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405902/null-pointer-exception-after-checking-with-if-statement)
- [NullPointerException thrown after field is check if it is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665495/nullpointerexception-thrown-after-field-is-check-if-it-is-null)

---

Here is the whole method (not sure if being in a thread mattered)

```
 private void setScoreTextSwitcher(final int a){
    Thread setScore = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            if(scoreTextSwitcher == null) {
                scoreTextSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.score_text_switcher);

            }
            GameActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if(scoreTextSwitcher != null) {
                        scoreTextSwitcher.setText(String.valueOf(a));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    setScore.start();
}
```

---

Here are the error messages:

```
08-27 11:02:10.226    2780-2780/com.major.color D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-27 11:02:10.226    2780-2780/com.major.color W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
08-27 11:02:10.247    2780-2780/com.major.color E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.TextSwitcher.setText(TextSwitcher.java:78)
            at com.major.color.GameActivity$6$1.run(GameActivity.java:600)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
```

---

Here is another section of my program that is also getting a null pointer error. I believe it's the same issue because it only occurs when starting and changing the screen orientation back and forth..  Hopefully this second example can help narrow things down a bit.

```
 private void startCountDownTimer(){
    isTimerOn = true;
    timerTextSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.timer_text_switcher);
    timer = new CountDownTimer(timerCount, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            isTimerOn = true;
            timerCount = millisUntilFinished;

            if ( millisUntilFinished < 10001) {
                TextView TextSwTextView = (TextView) timerTextSwitcher.getChildAt(0);
                TextSwTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                TextSwTextView.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
            }else
                if(timerTextSwitcher != null){
                    timerTextSwitcher.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));}else {
                    timerTextSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.timer_text_switcher);
                    timerTextSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {

                        public View makeView() {
                            // Create a new TextView and set properties
                            TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                            textView.setLayoutParams(new TextSwitcher.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            textView.setTextSize(17);
                            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

                            return textView;
                        }
                    });
                    timerTextSwitcher.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
                }
        }
   public void onFinish() {
            timerTextSwitcher.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    createToast("GAME OVER!");
                }
            });
            isTimerOn = false;

            saveScore();
            DialogFragment endDialog = new EndGameFragment();
            Dialog = endDialog;
            endgameVisible = true;
            endDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "EndGameDialogFragment");
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

---

Portion of onCreate method displaying how I setup the TextSwitcher for score and Time of activity.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game)
//more code...

 timerTextSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.timer_text_switcher);
    timerTextSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {

        public View makeView() {
            // Create a new TextView and set properties
            TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView.setLayoutParams(new TextSwitcher.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            textView.setTextSize(17);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

            return textView;
        }
    });
    scoreTextSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.score_text_switcher);
    scoreTextSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {

        public View makeView() {
            // Create a new TextView and set properties
            TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView.setLayoutParams(new TextSwitcher.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            textView.setTextSize(17);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            textView.setText("0");
            return textView;
        }
    });

    // Declare the animations and initialize them
    Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
    Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

    // set the animation type to textSwitcher
    timerTextSwitcher.setInAnimation(in);
    timerTextSwitcher.setInAnimation(out);
    scoreTextSwitcher.setInAnimation(in);
    scoreTextSwitcher.setInAnimation(out);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `a` is not null? and error is not on `String.valueOf(a)`?

Comment: Have you checked with some log statements whether your assumpion is correct?

Comment: @Dhruti that's what I thought at first.  I changed to 100 for testing and still failed.

Comment: A TextSwitcher is a ViewSwitcher used to animate text in and out. Do you want this, or a regular TextView? If you want the Switcher, you need to set it up appropriately. The problem isn't that `scoreTextSwitcher` is null.

Comment: YEs, I would like to animate the text in and out. I setup the view Factory and used setAnimation(in) within my onCreate() method to assign animation changes.  I edited my code to show what I did.

Comment: Then get rid of the calls to `findViewById()` in `setScoreTextSwitcher()` and `startCountDownTimer()`. They're wiping out all the setup you're doing.

Comment: I believe that's what I had initially but I'll try once more. one sec

Comment: @ Mike M.  That worked. Thank you very much for your assistance.  I understand that findviewbyID was wiping the viewfactory data, however, a bit confused on if scoreTextSwitcher is null when activity is recreated. I thought that when screen orinetation changes that activity is completely destroyed and starts over from oncreate-onstart-onresume.  I think my confusion lies with static variables and methods and when to release them by setting = to null. I thought it was during onStop or destroy but i'm doing something wrong... anywho, please post your answer so i can accept! :-)    Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you, but you're right in thinking the Activity will be recreated, and `onCreate()` will be called again. You don't need to declare any of your Views as `static`; they will be re-instantiated and re-initialized upon a configuration change. I'll post an answer a little later when I get to a desktop. Thanks! (Btw, when you use @name in a comment, take out all the spaces.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lines are causing the undesired behavior:

```
private void startCountDownTimer(){
    ...
    timerTextSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.timer_text_switcher);
```

and:

```
private void setScoreTextSwitcher(final int a){
    ...
    scoreTextSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.score_text_switcher);
```

These calls to `findViewById()` are re-initializing the Switchers, causing them to lose the Factory and Animation setups you've got in `onCreate()`, and causing an internal `NullPointerException` in the `setText()` method. Since, it appears, the Switchers are declared in the Activity's scope, you just need to remove those lines.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
private void setScoreTextSwitcher(final int a){
scoreTextSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.score_text_switcher);
Thread setScore = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        if(scoreTextSwitcher.isEmpty()) {
            Log.e("","Empty");

        }
        GameActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if(scoreTextSwitcher != null) {
                    scoreTextSwitcher.setText(String.valueOf(a));
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
setScore.start();
```

}

Comment: I'm going to be calling the method a lot; is it ok to keep using the findViewById() method?  I thought this was time consuming to do. I was hoping to avoid calling it each time I need to change the score and only when null??

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.  I'm getting a similar one in another section. I edited my post. Also, isEmpty() is a method for TextView, not Text Switcher.